# Should I include in the main file the headers that are already included in the .h file?

Tags: c, header-files

I have some functions (like stdio) that are included in the .h file, should I include them in the main file as well or it is useless?

Comment: It is better to include explicitly each used header in each translation unit.

Comment: don't write functions in header file (`.h`) instead write them in `.c` file add their declarations in `.h` file and include that `.h` where ever you want to use those functions

Comment: You can use as much headers as you want. Either a built-in `<>` or a custom `""` one, just make sure that you are looking for the right functions.

Comment: Look up the IWYU — Include What You Use — project.  It encourages you to explicitly include the headers that declare features your code uses, even if the header might be included tangentially by other headers.  This is a particular problem in C++ where standard headers are allowed to include other standard headers, whereas C only allows `inttypes.h>` to include `<stdint.h>`.  But even in C, including what you use is a good idea in case you stop using the header that coincidentally includes what you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `main.c` is a long file and uses both the standard library function `signal` and your routine `foo`. Also, `main.c` includes your header `"foo.h"`, which includes `<signal.h>`. `main.c` does not itself include `<signal.h>`.

This will compile, since the compiler sees a declaration of `signal` while compiling `main.c`, because `<signal.h>` is included by way of `"foo.h"`.

The next year, one of your coworkers reorganizes the software, and they move all of the code in `main.c` that uses `foo` out of `main.c` into `bar.c`. So they also move `#include "foo.h"` from `main.c` to `bar.c`. The other code in `main.c` that calls `signal` remains in `main.c`.

Now `main.c` will not compile, because it uses `signal`, but there is no include of `<signal.h>` in `main.c`, either directly or indirectly.

So, a habit of directly including in each source file a header file for each function (or other identifier) that the source file uses directly would avoid this issue.

However, it is a minor issue. The failure to compile will be noticed immediately and corrected promptly.

There can be other issues, such as an author might accidentally use a standard library function and forget to include the corresponding header, and the source code also contains a non-standard declaration of the same identifier. (It is easy not to remember the names of every identifier in the standard library and to use some of the simpler ones for other purposes.) Some compilers might warn about non-standard declarations that conflict with the standard library identifiers. However, your compiler does not, this situation can result in a buggy program, as the place where you intended to use a standard library function will instead use the alternate declaration. So always including a standard library header for the standard library functions you use can avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter if the include file has guards. You can include it as many times as you wish and the preprocessor will not include the "body" of the include file as it will be protected by the guards. Compilation time penalty on modern computers will not be noticeable by humans.

But remember in the header files you should not define any objects or functions. It should only contain data types declarations, function prototypes, macros, `extern` objects declaration and as an exception static inline function definitions.